# Python, find all the possible letter combinations in given morse code

Tags: python, decode, morse-code

I had to find all the possible letter combinations in a given morse code. The length of the **decoded** word can be **maximum 10 letters**. The given file with the letters and the morse code to it looks like this:

```
A   .-
B   -...
C   -.-.
D   -..
E   .
F   ..-.
G   --.
H   ....
I   ..
J   .---
K   -.-
L   .-..
M   --
N   -.
O   ---
P   .--.
Q   --.-
R   .-.
S   ...
T   -
U   ..-
V   ...-
W   .--
X   -..-
Y   -.--
Z   --..
```

The given morse code is this:

```
morse = '-.----.-.-...----.-.-.-.----.-'
```

My code looks like this:

```
def morse_file_to_dict(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return dict(line.strip().split() for line in file)


def word_to_morse(s, my_dict):
    return ''.join([my_dict[w] for w in s])


def adding_to_set(given_morse, my_set, my_dict, word='', start=0):
    for char in my_dict:
        if my_dict[char] == given_morse[start:start + len(my_dict[char])] and len(word) < 10:
            start = start + len(my_dict[char])
            word = word + char
            adding_to_set(given_morse, my_set, my_dict, word, start)
            if word_to_morse(word, my_dict) == given_morse:
                my_set.add(word)


words = set()
morse = '-.----.-.-...----.-.-.-.----.-'
pairs = morse_file_to_dict('morse_alphabet.txt')
adding_to_set(morse, words, pairs)
print(len(words))
print(words)
```

My output is:

```
5
{'KMCBMQRKMK', 'KMCBMGKRMQ', 'KMCBMGCKMK', 'KMNCEJCCMQ', 'KMCDAMCCMQ'}
```

**BUT, the answer should be: 10571 words, not 5**

What should i change to get all of them?
Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: You need to properly get back so that `for` can go further. When you do backtracking you need to: set your new value, do a recursion, AND remove that new value. To do that: DON'T overwrite `word` nor `start`, use some `new_word` and `new_start`, so you keep the old values for further `for` runs!

Comment: BTW, this: `my_dict[char] == given_morse[start:start + len(my_dict[char])]` may be written a bit more concisely as `given_morse[start:].startswith(my_dict[char])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using recursion and a dictionary to map morse code to letters (not letters to morse code):

```
morseFile="""A   .-
B   -...
C   -.-.
D   -..
E   .
F   ..-.
G   --.
H   ....
I   ..
J   .---
K   -.-
L   .-..
M   --
N   -.
O   ---
P   .--.
Q   --.-
R   .-.
S   ...
T   -
U   ..-
V   ...-
W   .--
X   -..-
Y   -.--
Z   --.."""

morse = {code:letter for line in morseFile.split("\n") for letter,code in [line.split()]}
```

The function can be built as a generator to avoid storing all the possibilities in a big list:

```
def decode(coded,maxLen=10):
    if not maxLen: return
    for size in range(1,min(4,len(coded))+1):
        code = coded[:size]
        if code not in morse: continue
        remaining = coded[size:]
        if not remaining: yield morse[code]
        for rest in decode(remaining,maxLen-1):
            yield morse[code] + rest
```

output:

```
print(sum(1 for _ in decode("-.----.-.-...----.-.-.-.----.-")))

10571

for string in decode("-.----.-.-...----.-.-.-.----.-"):
    if len(string)<9: print(string)

YQLWGCYQ
YQLWQRYQ
YQLJNCYQ
YQLJKRYQ
YQLJCNYQ
YQLJCKWQ
YQLJCKJK
YQLJCCMQ
YQLJCCOK
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution. I made changes from codes and suggestions in comments and answers. (The Morse to translate is different too)

```
    def word_to_morse(s, my_dict):
        return ''.join([my_dict[w] for w in s])

    def adding_to_set(given_morse, my_set, my_dict, word='', start=0):
        for char in my_dict:
            if my_dict[char] == given_morse[start:start + len(my_dict[char])] and len(word) < 10:
                new_start = start + len(my_dict[char])
                new_word = word + char
                adding_to_set(given_morse, my_set, my_dict, new_word, new_start)
                if word_to_morse(new_word, my_dict) == given_morse:
                    my_set.add(new_word)
    words = set()

    # the morse code I want to decrypt
    morse = '.-.--...-....-.'

    # adding morse alphabet here
    pairs={'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',   'C': '-.-.', 
           'D': '-..',    'E': '.',      'F': '..-.',
           'G': '--.',    'H': '....',   'I': '..',
           'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',    'L': '.-..',
           'M': '--',     'N': '-.',     'O': '---',
           'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',   'R': '.-.',
           'S': '...',    'T': '-',      'U': '..-',
           'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',    'X': '-..-',
           'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',

     
    }
    adding_to_set(morse, words, pairs)
    print(len(words))
    print(words)
```

Comment: Your code produces 8449 possible letter combinations.  The OP states that there should be 10571 possible combinations.  Is your code missing some combinations, or is 8449 actually the number of possible combinations?  I'm assuming there's some equation for calculating the number of possible combinations?

Comment: Because the Morse code I want to translate is different from the OP. If you put back his morse code, you will get the 10571 combinations.

Answer (score -2):

c++ solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char buffer[26];
int l=0;
char *Morse[26];
//initializing Morse Code array
void initMorse(){
Morse[0] = "._" ;            
Morse[1] = "_...";            
Morse[2] = "_._." ;            
Morse[3] = "_.." ;            
Morse[4] = "." ;   //E         
Morse[5] = ".._." ;            
Morse[6] = "__." ;            
Morse[7] = "...." ;  //H          
Morse[8] = ".." ;       //I     
Morse[9] = ".___" ;   //J         
Morse[10] = "_._" ;  //K            
Morse[11] = "._.." ;            
Morse[12] = "__" ;   //M         
Morse[13] = "_." ;            
Morse[14] = "___" ;     //O       
Morse[15] = ".__." ;  //P            
Morse[16] = "__._" ;            
Morse[17] = "._." ;   //R         
Morse[18] = "..." ;            
Morse[19] = "_" ;            
Morse[20] = ".._" ;            
Morse[21] = "..._" ;  //V          
Morse[22] = ".__" ;            
Morse[23] = "_.._" ;            
Morse[24] = "_.__" ;            
Morse[25] = "__.." ; //Z
}
int solution(char *s,int strt,char **Morse,int len){
    int i,j,noMatch=0,k,prev,tem;
    int mlen;
    if(strt!=len)
    for(i=0;i<26;i++){
    mlen=strlen(Morse[i]);
     if(strt+mlen<=len){
        for(j=strt,k=0;j<strt+mlen&&k<mlen;j++,k++){
            if(Morse[i][k]==s[j])
                continue;
            else {
                noMatch=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        continue;   
    }
    if(noMatch==0){
         //print pattern when complete string matched
         if(strt+mlen==len){
          buffer[l]=i+65;
             printf("%s\n",buffer);
             buffer[l]=0;
        }
        else{
            noMatch=0;  
            buffer[l]=i+65;
            l++;
            solution(s,strt+mlen,Morse,len);
            l--;                 // while backtracking 
            buffer[l]=0;      //  clearing buffer just upto the previous location 
        }
    }
    else{
        noMatch=0;
    }
}
else{
    buffer[l]=0;
}
return 1;
}

int main() {

char s[100];
printf("Enter the input string of Morse code:\n");
scanf("%s",s);
initMorse();
printf("Possible translations are:\n");
solution(s,0,Morse,strlen(s));
for
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anyone asking for a **C++** solution…

Comment: @Błotosmętek if anyone knows programming then they can easily interpret and convert it to their own language  and if not then they should learn.

Comment: I get some empty strings and a segfault on this string: .._._._.._..._..._......__.._.__.___.._____._

Comment: Also you have a mis-placed `for` right before the end of `main`