# Trying to skips steps in a riddle my friend made with morse code by brute force in python

Tags: python, friend

I used the following code from a another's question to brute force the morse code with all letters, but didn't seem to make any words that would make sense. How can I add numbers and punctuation to this code? I'm not a coder, so help would be greatly appreciated! As for the morse code itself: "--...--.------.-----------" there might be spaces between words making it "--...--.-- ----.---- -------"

[Python, find all the possible letter combinations in given morse code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211691/python-find-all-the-possible-letter-combinations-in-given-morse-code)

```
morseFile="""A   .-
B   -...
C   -.-.
D   -..
E   .
F   ..-.
G   --.
H   ....
I   ..
J   .---
K   -.-
L   .-..
M   --
N   -.
O   ---
P   .--.
Q   --.-
R   .-.
S   ...
T   -
U   ..-
V   ...-
W   .--
X   -..-
Y   -.--
Z   --.."""

morse = {code:letter for line in morseFile.split("\n") for letter,code in [line.split()]}

def decode(coded,maxLen=10):
    if not maxLen: return
    for size in range(1,min(4,len(coded))+1):
        code = coded[:size]
        if code not in morse: continue
        remaining = coded[size:]
        if not remaining: yield morse[code]
        for rest in decode(remaining,maxLen-1):
            yield morse[code] + rest

print(sum(1 for _ in decode("-.----.-.-...----.-.-.-.----.-")))


for string in decode("-.----.-.-...----.-.-.-.----.-"):
    if len(string)<9: print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved with recursion. To put it simply, we see if a letter fits into the start of the code, add it to the result and repeat.

However, I warn you in advance. Because there are so many ways to squeeze letters like E, T, etc into the code and without identifying spaces, you get roughly 10000+ results for your text: a *lot* of nitty-gritty sifting through to do.

This is a working solution to the problem:

[Aside from the excessive comments, the code is relatively straightforward]

```
# +----------------------+
# |Morse Code from String|
# +----------------------+

# Define letters & chars -- this can be altered where need be
morse =  { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
                    'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
                    'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
                    'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-',
                    'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
                    'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-',
                    'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
                    'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--',
                    'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--',
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....',
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
                    '0':'-----'}

# Input value
string = "-....-"

# Recursive function
# - Every time we run this, we check to see if starting characters fit.
# - If so, we run it again minus that character, and return the results
# - The results get exponentially larger proportional to the string
def FindCombinations(code):
    
    # Check for empty
    if code == "":
        return []
    # Get the results / output ready
    out = []
    
    # Iterate through with each character
    # - it can also be done vice versa (if need be), meaning check the code then get the character
    for char in morse:
        
        # Check if character code fits in
        if code.startswith(morse[char]):
           
            # Run recursive minus the current letter to generate the next set of results and add the current to them
            results = FindCombinations(code[len(morse[char]):])
            
            # If a result exists, add the character to the front, then to the overall results
            if results != []:
                for result in results:
                    out.append(char + result)
                    
            # Otherwise, add the current letter
            else:
                out.append(char)
                
    # Return all the generated results
    return out

# Test the given string and show the results
print(FindCombinations(string))
```

To test out any combination, put it in the `string` variable.

To refine your search, you can reduce the characters here and there in the `morse` dictionary.

Comment: Hi @ClavaBrighteagle , just wondering of the code worked... If so, it would be really handy if you could give it an upvote and a best answer. A lot of work went into it. Thanks, Larry